# ajax type:"GET" works for firefox and chrome but not for IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, methods, get

Hey guys this works for Firefox and Chrome in that it passes the data fine and shows the confirmationpage

but when i run it on IE it just refreshes the page and the data is all NULL while passing

```
 var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&areacode=' +     areacode + '&phonenumber=' + phonenumber + '&emailaddress=' + emailaddress + '&confirmemail=' +     confirmemail + '&password=' + password + '&streetaddress=' + streetaddress + '&streetaddress2=' + streetaddress2 + '&city=' + city + '&state=' + state + '&zipcode=' + zipcode + '&month=' + month + '&day=' + day + '&year=' + year + '&services=' + services + '&agreement=' + agreement; 
  //alert(dataString); 
 // alert(services); 
 //var d = new Date(); 
  $.ajax({
     // cache: false, 
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.vectorcreditsolution.com/js/process.php",
    data: dataString,
  //  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",  
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.href ="thankyou.html";
    }
    });
return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you verified what is arriving at your server (maybe populate a session variable) to ensure your `$.ajax()` is sending what you think it is?

2) Have you tried

```
var dataString = $("#formId").serializeArray();
```

(assuming `<form id="formId"...`)? And then use that for your `data:dataString,` element

3) I would expect you would want code something on the server when it is done processing to respond back to your calling page, and then in the `success:function(retData)` evaluate retData to interpret the server's response. If you simply don't care what happens and just want the browser page to march blindly forward to your thankyou.html upon completion of the ajax call, you don't need to include an argument variable in the function:

```
success: function() {...},
```